# Problems with solid & wireframe view (only piece of object visible)

Tags: 3d-view

Please see attached screenshots
[image: Solid View Poroblem]

Comment: Youcan attach your .blend file. Maybe it is a bug. Or try swithching to camera view in the right panel. Before that remain in front orthographic and go into rendered view.

Comment: Well, it looks like a bug. Rendered view and material preview function works normal while solid view and wireframe view show only a portion of the object. This problem appears in normal view as well as camera. Project renders normally. How Can I attached file here?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's normal behaviour when faces are hidden, see my answer below.

Comment: I've tried, the suggestion below was great, but it's not this... unfortunately

Comment: Please add more text information to your post, or add the blend file or part of it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have hidden the faces below the top, which means, in *Edit Mode* with the bottom faces selected you've hit the <kbd>H</kbd> key to *Hide Selected Faces* or with the top faces selected you've hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to *Hide Unselected Faces*

In the left window you've set the shading option to *Rendered*, then even hidden faces are visible. To let them reappear in *Solid Shading* (i.e. the right window) hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to *Reveal Hidden Faces*.

Comment: The very good try, but nope, Tha't not it;(

Comment: I've moved all the collections to new file and everything seem to like normal, but still i don't know what's the reason behind this problem.

Comment: If that's not the problem here, please consider uploading your file here for closer examination: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have hidden vertices. Just go into edit mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: unfortunately it's not this;/

Comment: Can you upload the blend file? It's pretty hard to find the issue with just a screenshot.